# Outlet drain hose of my washing machine must go all the way to the top of the machine?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I have just purchased a Samsung front load washing machine (7kg capacity).

So when I was studying its emplacement, I have decided that its drain hose would be over the floor to a avoid an obstacle (the cupboard wood wall). And then it would come up to be plugged to my kitchen siphon.

The problem is that apparently Samsung obliges that the drain hose goes all the way to the top of the machine by means of a security screw.

I have successfully removed it, but I am not sure if it could cause problems with my washing machine. Could it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best solution in my case was to raise the drain hose near the kitchen siphon. In that way, I prevent any dirt to be sent to the washing machine.

It also prevents that gravity empties the machine, since the highest point of the hose is higher than the machine water level.

Unfortunately, if the pump is not designed to work in that configuration, there is nothing I can do. I think it may increase the pump workload, as the hose goes first down an then up, but I simply cannot afford a drain pipe closer to it.

I have run two washing cycles and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Down and back up adds as much pressure in one direction as in the other, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want this in place, so before removing it, I'd check with the manufacturer to see if they permit it. I can think of at least three reasons you'd want the drain line secured at this height:

1. Drain hoses for appliances like dishwashers and washing machines that run into a sink drain are installed above, or as close to the top of the sink drain to ensure any clog in the sink backs into the sink itself, and not siphoned into the nearby dishwasher or washing machine. You don't want to find waste from the sink in the bottom of your washing machine.
2. You also need this line above the high water level of the washing machine so it doesn't siphon out while washing.
3. Keeping the high point of the line immediately adjacent to the machine with these security clips reduces the effort of the pump and how much water may drain back into the machine after it completes its wash cycle. The manufacturer will have a better understanding of their pump's requirements.

Comment: So the solution would be to buy a longer drain hose, so I could maintain the security screw there and still reach my kitchen siphon?

Comment: That gets back to the manufacturer, the pump may not support a longer drain line. But if the entire run is downhill shortly after it reaches the a high point as close to the washing machine as possible, and that height is supported by the pump, a longer run should be fine.

Comment: does the screwed drain hose as shown in the picture mean no standpipe is needed?